# Importing Product data doesn't show meta value

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, metadata

I am facing very strange issue. I am working on woocomerce based wordpress site, in which I have imported about more than 1 lack product form XML programatically, My problem is product meta data named **Related Product** saved in database, Displayed in back-end, But not displayed on single product page on front-end. But when I manually update post from back-end then after it displayed. It is not possible for me to manually update more than 1 lack post. So I decided to create function that will update post.

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'my_update_posts' );
if ( $_REQUEST['test'] == 1 ) {

    function my_update_posts() {

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'numberposts' => -1
        );
       $myposts = get_posts($args);

        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($myposts); die;

        foreach ( $myposts as $mypost ) {
            if ( $mypost->ID == 17 ) {
                 //$mypost->title = "test";
                 wp_update_post( $mypost );
             }
        }
    }
}
```

So I created this function and tested but it will update/save post data like content and title, and not updating/saving meta data.

I want create function that can save post programatically, including meta data.[image]

Comment: Small issue, you should put the `if` statement inside the function. Otherwise you might get a php error `function undefined`.

Comment: @loictheaztec I have all the data in database but they need to manually update post in back-end. so  will fire this function by passing REQUEST parameter, so that post will update and i don't need to do that manually.

Comment: @ParthaviPatel This doesn't make your question more clear as you have already explained that in your question… This doesn't answer to: what post data? what meta data? where (how) do you get it from?

Comment: @loictheaztec Okay ..... when I fire my function it update post data like "title", "content".  And meta data name is **Related Product**. All these data i am importing from XML.

Comment: @ParthaviPatel You should please update your question with all necessary details and explanations making some real effort if you want to have any chances to get some helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to save post data is using the [update_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/) function.
I have no idea how Woocommerce saves the related products. Keep in mind that it might make more then one meta field, maybe even create meta in the other related post.

Hope this helps, your question is a bit vague.